# How to Tune Isolation Forest?

Tags: outliers, k-nearest-neighbour, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

Many online blogs talk about using Isolation Forest for anomaly detection. But I got a very poor result. The data used is [house prices](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques) data from Kaggle. I used IForest and KNN from pyod to identify 1% of data points as outliers.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyod.models.knn import KNN
from pyod.models.iforest import IForest

df = pd.read_csv("house_prices_train.csv")
clf1 = IForest(contamination=0.01, random_state=10)
clf1.fit(df[['SalePrice','TotalBsmtSF']])

clf2 = KNN(contamination=0.01)
clf2.fit(df[['SalePrice','TotalBsmtSF']])
```

Then I used the output from predict and decision_function functions to create the following contour plots. As you can see the data point in the right hand side is farthest away from the majority of the data, but it is inside the decision boundary produced by IForest and classified as normal while KNN classify it correctly as an outlier. Is it because IForest requires some hyperparameter tuning in order to get good results?? Also I notice using different random_state values for IForest will produce quite different decision boundaries so it seems IForest is quite unstable while KNN is much more stable in this regard.

[image]

Comment: You can use GridSearch for grid searching on the parameters.
Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56078831/isolation-forest-parameter-tuning-with-gridsearchcv) that talks about it.

Comment: That's the way isolation forest works unfortunately. You might get better results from using smaller sample sizes. You can also look the "extended isolation forest" model (not currently in scikit-learn nor pyod).